# jquery form.validate does not work

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery-validate

I'm current working on jquery and have a problem about the validation usage. I　made a code for register but when i run it, nothing happened and there's no error show up, either. can anyone help me with that?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="js/signup-form.js"></script>
    <script>
        $().ready(function () {
            $("#registerForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    userName: {
                        required: true,
                        minLength: 8
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8
                    },
                    passwordConfirmation: {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        required: "This field can not be empty",
                        email: "Email address does not valid"
                    },
                    userName: {
                        required: "This field can not be empty",
                        minLength: "UserName must contain at least 8 charactors"
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: "This field can not be empty",
                        minLength: "Password must contain at least 8 charactors"
                    },
                    passwordConfirmation: {
                        required: "This field can not be empty",
                        equalTo: "Please enter the same password above"
                    }
                }

            });

        });

    </script>
    <form id="registerForm">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" value="@Model.Email" name="email" id="email" />


                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input tyep="text" value="@Model.UserName" name="username"/>


                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" value="@Model.Password" name="password"/>

                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" value="@Model.PasswordConfirmation" name="passwordConfirmation" />

                </p>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" vaule="Register" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

when i hit the register button, nothing happened and there's no error.  can anyone help me out with that?
by the way, i using visual studio MVC 5, does that make any problem?
thanks!!!

@edit:
i have tried my code at hjsfiddle.net/5d1b50k6 and it works fine. but it still not working in my computer.  does mvc would affect that??

Comment: The code you've presented to us is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/5d1b50k6/

Comment: `$().ready(...)` should be `$(document).ready(...)`;  and you've misspelled `minlength` as `minLength`.

Comment: @Sparky  i tried that early,  it not work either.  but thanks for correcting the mistake.

Comment: @Sparky  so do you think my mvc might be the problem??  i am using visual studio

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio as I prefer to have more control over my code.   Do you know how to use it?  Are you using the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin?  If so, that would be taking precedence over your `.validate()` method.

Comment: im not sure. how can i know that??

Comment: It sounds like you need to take a step back and read the documentation for your Visual Studio framework.  At least I gave you something to look for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15046117/594235

Comment: i think i do have the unobrtrusive -validation. what should i do now?

Comment: You need to disable it if you want to use jQuery Validate manually.  You should read the documentation that came with Visual Studio and ASP/MVC or whatever other technologies you are using.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

On line 6, add # to select the ID:

```
$("#registerForm").validate({
```

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: thank you for catching that mistake. but it still not working and have no error showing up