# How to detect whether Data Annotations validations were unsuccessful?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC page with fields like this...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyField, new { @class = "form-control",  data_val_required = "Required field" })
```

Also, I have a JavaScript validation function called from the "onsubmit" event of the form...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { @onsubmit = "return validateDeep();" }))
```

And I need to detect whether the Data Annotation validations were successfull or not. I investigated and found the "Page_IsValid" variable, which unfortunately is always undefined.

```
function validateDeep()
{
   var errors = "";
   if (!Page_IsValid) // this fails, also this: document.Page_IsValid
       errors = errors + "- There are empty fields (marked in red color)<br/>";

   errors = errors +  getOtherValidationErrors();

   if (errors != "") {
      openAlert("ERRORS!<br/>" + errors);
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

So, the question is... how to detect that those data-annotation validations, in the client side and before the Post, were not successful?

Comment: You want to know it in server ? `var isValid = ModelState.IsValid` ?

Comment: So you cant use the standart attributes like `[Required]` and [validate them using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046117/how-to-manually-enable-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-mvc)?

Comment: This is at client level (JavaScript). Change validations to the [Required] attribute is not an option because there are many forms already in the project.

Comment: What do you think adding `data_val_required = "Required field"` will do if you do not have a `[Required]` attribute, and do not have `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` included?

Answer (score 0):

-- Deleted wrong answer --

My first answer was wrong, I unterstand the szenario of OP now like this:

- Form is posted to the server
- server returns form because `ModelState.IsValid == false`
- page gets rendered with errors and served to client
- how do I detect the existing errors on the client?

If you render the errors with `@Html.ValidationSummary()`, the generated markup will look like this [[1]](http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.com/2013/03/validationsummary-html-helper-in-mvc3.html):

```
<span style="font-family: inherit;"><div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
        <ul>
           <li>List of error messages ...</li>
        </ul>
   </div> 
</span>
```

So `data-valmsg-summary="true"` tells us that there have been validation errors, i.e. Data Annotation validations were unsuccessfull.

```
 // using jQuery 1.7.2
 var invalid = $('.validation-summary-errors').data('valmsg-summary');
 if (invalid) {
     // some javascript ...
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to revalidate with, append and learn other library. I want to know the result of the already existent validation of the ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: Sorry I misunterstood your question. You want to check whether the server found any errors after the roundtrip. We did this by searching through the HTML rendered by the [ValidationSummary HTML Helper](http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.com/2013/03/validationsummary-html-helper-in-mvc3.html).

Comment: This happens (the validation) before the form is being posted. Notice that the function is called from the onsubmit event, which will only make the post if the returned value is true. Thanks for the try.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The validation based on data-val-required can be evaluated with this...

```
var form = $("#MyForm");
if (!form.valid())
    alert("You have incomplete/invalid values, please correct them");
```

This validation is based on the "unobtrusive" JQuery validations, not on the ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations validations.